# For rtl languages, how to right-align v-text-field label?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-text-field like this:

```
<v-text-field v-model="username" label="نام کاربری" />
```

But the label appears on the left, is there any way to make it appear on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify rtl option where you bootstrap vuetify (in vuetify constructor options). Labels will automatically appear on right side.

```
new Vuetify({
    rtl: true,
    // other options
})
```

You can update rtl option dynamically in vue component like this

```
this.$vuetify.rtl = true // or false
```

Comment: oh I had done this: `Vue.use(Vuetify, {rtl: true});`

Answer (score 1):

**In Vue js 3 or Nuxtjs 3:** The following example demonstrates how to force RTL for a specific section of your content, without switching the current language, by using the `v-locale-provider` component:

```
<v-app>
  <v-card>...</v-card> <!-- default locale used here -->

  <v-locale-provider rtl>
    <v-card>...<v-card> <!-- default locale used here, but with RTL active -->
  </v-locale-provider>
</v-app>
```

**For example:**

```
<v-locale-provider rtl>
     <v-text-field v-model="username" label="نام کاربری" />
</v-locale-provider>
```